# Staging, production, development branch (what am I doin' wrong?)

Tags: git

So, I have a development, staging, and master branch. And I have an heroku host for staging and production.

Now I lets say I do the following:

```
git checkout development
make some changes 
commit -a -m them and push them.
```

then I run

```
git checkout staging
git merge development
```

and I get the following error:

```
Auto-merging app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Why is this?

Comment: At some point you made changes to staging branch and committed which you didn't merge back to development branch before making change to the file in development branch which is the reason for that conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is telling you that you have a conflict in the following file `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` that Git cannot resolve by itself.

This happens when you performed a change on the same file from 2 different branches. If the changes are too close together or too similar, Git could have issues merging them.

Simply edit the file `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` to remove the conflict and help git merging the file.

Comment: that seems about right, but why is when I make a change on staging and git commit, git push staging master it says everything is up to date. When everything isn't up to date?

Comment: You seems new to git and this is great ! Please read through the first chapters to understand how git works http://git-scm.com/book/en Have fun!